# popup abrir apenas 1 vez após ser fechada, mesmo depois de recarregar página

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como criar um daqueles `popup` que geralmente aparecem em grandes portais *(não em flash)*, mas com `div` e `javascript` puro, que após ser fechada, o `script` detecte isso e ele não abra mais, mesmo depois de recarregar a página ou navegar entre as páginas internas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você vai precisar controlar se a exibição do popup já foi feita para um dado usuário, e para isso existem algumas formas:

Para exibir o popup pode usar uma biblioteca já pronta:

- [jquery ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) - meu exemplo vai ser usando este
- [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

**Armazenar no client:**

Armazenar a informação no lado do cliente, usando alguma das formas de storage do browser: cookie, localstorage, sessionstorage.

- **cookie:** armazena a informação na forma de cookie, que tem uma data específica para expirar, neste caso após essa data, o cookie seria exibido novamente, obviamente é possível definir uma data muito distante, de forma que pareça ser para sempre. Infelizmente, o javascript não possui uma função bonitinha para fazer isso, entretanto é a forma que vai funcionar com a maior quantidade de browseres. Se estiver usando jQuery, pode usar o plugin **[jquery.cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)**:

  ```
  // verificando se o cookie está setado, caso contrário exibe o popup
  if (!$.cookie("popup-exibida"))
  {
       // exibir popup usando a sua lib de popup preferida
  }
  ```

  Código do popup (usando [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)):

  ```
  $(function() {
      $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
          height: 140,
          close: function( event, ui ) {
              var date = new Date();
              var minutes = 30;
              date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
              $.cookie("popup-exibida", "1", { expires: date }); // expira em 30 minutos
          }
      });
  });
  ```
- **sessionstorage:** armazena a informação na sessão de navegação do usuário, que é descartada pelo browser quando este é fechado, portanto a informação se perde ao fechar o browser. Esse recurso é bem mais fácil de usar do que cookies, mas é um recurso mais novo, e requer um browser mais moderno:

  ```
  // verificando se o storage possui a variável setada, caso contrário exibe o popup
  if (!window.sessionStorage.getItem("popup-exibida"))
  {
       // exibir popup usando a sua lib de popup preferida
  }
  ```

  Setando a variável no session-storage

  ```
   // setar cookie para impedir uma nova exibição
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("popup-exibida", "1");
  ```
- **localstorage:** armazena a informação de forma permanente, no computador do usuário, sendo que se ele trocar de computador o popup seria exibido novamente. Esse recurso é parecido com o sessionStorage em termos de praticidade, e também é um recurso recente, então a compatibilidade é restrita aos navegadores mais modernos:

  ```
  // verificando se o storage possui a variável setada, caso contrário exibe o popup
  if (!window.localStorage.getItem("popup-exibida"))
  {
       // exibir popup usando a sua lib de popup preferida
  }
  ```

  Setando a variável no local-storage

  ```
   // setar cookie para impedir uma nova exibição
   window.localStorage.setItem("popup-exibida", "1");
  ```

**Armazenar no servidor:**

Armazenar a informação no lado do servidor, usando sessão de navegação do usuário ou um banco de dados, ou outro que preferir. No javascript teria de fazer uma chamada ajax quando o popup fosse fechado, indicando ao servidor que o popup não deve mais ser renderizado no output.

- **sessão de navegação:** Armazenar na sessão de navegação do usuário no servidor, sendo que ao expirar a informação se perde. As tecnologias de programação web que eu conheço, todas fornecem uma sessão de navegação, que permite armazenar a informação.
- **banco de dados:** Caso seja um usuário logado no sistema, poderia armazenar essa informação em um banco de dados no servidor, assim a informação seria persistente por todas a existência daquele usuário.

Answer (score 4):

Aqui uma solução sem jQuery. O exemplo de funções para Cookie [desta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20604307/1287812) e o DOMReady [desta outra também no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196548/1287812). O CSS é do [plugin Reveal Modal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin), mas usei só para testes e removi todo o jQuery do plugin neste exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Popup Demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            /* From http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin */
            body { 
                font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
                }
            .texto {
                display:block; 
                margin-top: 100px; 
                text-align: center; 
                font-size: 70px; 
                color: #06f; 
                }
            .reveal-modal-bg { 
                position: fixed; 
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background: #000;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
                z-index: 100;
                display: none;
                top: 0;
                left: 0; 
                }

            .reveal-modal {
                visibility: hidden;
                top: 100px; 
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -300px;
                width: 520px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 101;
                padding: 30px 40px 34px;
                }


            .reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
                font-size: 22px;
                line-height: .5;
                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                right: 11px;
                color: #aaa;
                text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
                font-weight: bold;
                cursor: pointer;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p class="texto">Conteúdo normal da página</p>

        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
            <h1>Exemplo de popup modal</h1>
            <p>Ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* From https://stackoverflow.com/a/20604307/1287812 */
        function setCookie( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d ) 
        {
            var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape(value);
            var expires = new Date(exp_y, exp_m, exp_d);
            cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cookie_string;
        }

        /* From https://stackoverflow.com/a/20604307/1287812 */
        function getCookie( cookie_name) 
        {
            var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return results ? unescape(results[2]) : null;
        }

        /* From https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196548/1287812 */
        var execute = function () 
        {
            if( !getCookie('popup') ) 
            {
                document.getElementById('myModal').style.visibility = 'visible';
                setCookie('popup', 'visto', 2014, 4, 12);
            }
            else
                console.log('cookie já definido');

        };

        /* From https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196548/1287812 */
        if ( !!(window.addEventListener) )
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", execute)
        else // MSIE
            window.attachEvent("onload", execute)

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente você aplica uma Fancybox com o banner e seta um Cookie no navegador. Depois verifca: SE esse Cookie ainda existir ele não exibe mais a Popup. Depois que ele expira (você seta o numero de dias/horas/minutos/etc) ou quando se limpar os cookies, ele volta a aparecer.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo pro garoto ! :)

Comment: imaginei algo com cookies mesmo. mas daí, lembrei que cookies ainda não é minha praia.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo feito com [`jQuery Cookie`](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Exemplo</title>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.modal.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="jquery.modal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        /*Confere se sts já existe na Cookie*/
        if ($.cookie('sts') != '1')
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {        
            $("#data").modal(); /*Executa o Modal*/       
                /*Gerando os dados do Cookie*/
                var date = new Date(); 
                var tempo = 30; // minutos 
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (tempo * 60 * 1000));
                jQuery.cookie('sts', '1', { expires: date });
            }, 1000);
        }

    });     
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<!--https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal-->
<div style="display:none" id="data" class="modal">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Armazenamento no Cliente, evita acessos no servidor e faz um melhor controle de um modal simples, tendo no `Jquery Cookie` um rotina simples com configuração de expiração de **30 minutos**

***Referencias:***

- [The simplest possible modal for jQuery](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)
- [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)