# modal abrir somente uma vez enquanto a pagina nao ser fechada

Tags: javascript, jquery

como fazer para quando a pagina for recarregada o modal que eu criei nao abrir novamente, mas quando eu fechar a pagina e abrir denovo o modal abrir novamente como faco isso?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6"><img src="images/send.png"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6"><h3 align="center" id="cor">Deseja Receber Nossas Novidades em <br>Primeira Mão </h3></div>
        <div align="center" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h4 align="center" id="cor">Inscreva-se para receber novidades</h4>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder=" Digite seu nome completo." size="25">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder=" Digite seu E-mail." size="30">

        </div>
        <div align="center" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <button id="primary" class="btn">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem o JSFiddle dele?

Comment: nao tenho amigo

Comment: eu so criei uma function e dentro dei show no modal so tenho isso e logico a parte php que vai receber esse modal

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/wscbohdy/

Comment: Pergunta semelhante http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12639/popup-abrir-apenas-1-vez-ap%C3%B3s-ser-fechada-mesmo-depois-de-recarregar-p%C3%A1gina?rq=1

Comment: Isso mesmo @PedroCamaraJunior. Já existe uma resposta para a sua dúvida Leandro Costa

Comment: obg pelo comentario ai vou dar uma lida na pergunta existente valew